# Globally disable QoS on Cisco 3750 in production

Tags: cisco, qos, cisco-ios

I suspect some issues with faulty QoS settings on a 3750 stack running in a 24x7 environment. The 3750 mainly routes between vlans on a lan segment. Since it is a lan device (not terminating any wan links) i want to globally disable QoS (`no mls qos`), I prefer to run QoS only on wan links.

I will be doing this on a off-peak moment but want to find out what impact on the trunks and access links this will cause? Will it cause a disruption? And does it clear any custom QoS settings or does these remain but ignored? Cant seem to find a conclusive answer..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will cause zero disruption. I've done it in the middle of the day before.

Any policies will remain, but ignored

Comment: Configuration statemnts will stay there, but QoS informations will be cleared ( set to all-zeros ) during the forwarding process.